# Decoding and using JSON data in Perl

Tags: json, perl

I am confused about accessing the contents of some JSON data that I have decoded. Here is an example

I don't understand why this solution works and my own does not. My questions are rephrased below

```
my $json_raw = getJSON(); 
my $content  = decode_json($json_raw);
print Data::Dumper($content);
```

At this point my JSON data has been transformed into this

```
$VAR1 = { 'items' => [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] };
```

My guess tells me that, once decoded, the object will be a hash with one element that has the key `items` and an array reference as the value.

```
$content{'items'}[0]
```

where `$content{'items'}` would obtain the array reference, and the outer `$...[0]` would access the first element in the array and interpret it as a scalar. However this does not work. I get an error message `use of uninitialized value [...]`

However, the following does work:

```
$content->{items}[0]
```

where `$content->{items}` yields the array reference and `[0]` accesses the first element of that array.

Questions

- Why does `$content{'items'}` not return an array reference? I even tried `@{content{'items'}}`, thinking that, once I got the value from `content{'items'}`, it would need to be interpreted as an array. But still, I receive the uninitialized array reference.
- How can I access the array reference without using the arrow operator?

Comment: Read [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for information on references and their usage.

Comment: Your first problem was failing to `use strict;` which would have caught your mistake.

Comment: Re "Wny does `$content{'items'}` not return an array reference?" Because you never assigned anything to that variable, `%content`.

Answer (score 15):

Beginner's answer to beginner :) Sure not as profesional as should be, but maybe helps you.

```
use strict;    #use this all times
use warnings;  #this too - helps a lot!
use JSON;

my $json_str = '    { "items" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }    ';
my $content = decode_json($json_str);
```

You wrote:

> My guess tells me that, once decoded, the object will be a hash with
>   one element that has the key items and an array reference as the value.

Yes, it is a hash, but the the `decode_json` returns a reference, in this case, the reference to hash. (from the docs)

> expects an UTF-8 (binary) string and tries to parse that
>   as an UTF-8 encoded JSON text,
>   returning the resulting **reference**.

In the line

```
my $content = decode_json($json_str);
```

you assigning to an SCALAR variable (not to hash).

Because you know: it is a reference, you can do the next:

```
printf "reftype:%s\n", ref($content);
#print: reftype:HASH       ^   
           #therefore the  +------- is a SCALAR value containing a reference to hash
```

It is a hashref - you can dump all keys

```
print "key: $_\n" for keys %{$content}; #or in short %$content
#prints: key: items
```

also you can assing the value of the "items" (arrayref) to an scalar variable

```
my $aref = $content->{items};   #$hashref->{key}
#or
#my $aref = ${$content}{items}; #$hash{key}
```

but **NOT**

```
#my $aref = $content{items};    #throws error if "use strict;"
#Global symbol "%content" requires explicit package name at script.pl line 20.
```

The `$content{item}` is requesting a value from the hash `%content` and you never defined/assigned such variable. the `$content` is an scalar variable not hash variable `%content`.

```
{
    #in perl 5.20 you can also
    use 5.020;
    use experimental 'postderef';
    print "key-postderef: $_\n" for keys $content->%*;
}
```

Now step deeper - to the arrayref - again you can print out the reference type

```
printf "reftype:%s\n", ref($aref);
#reftype:ARRAY
```

print all elements of array

```
print "arr-item: $_\n" for @{$aref};
```

but again **NOT**

```
#print "$_\n" for @aref;
#dies: Global symbol "@aref" requires explicit package name at script.pl line 37.

{
    #in perl 5.20 you can also
    use 5.020;
    use experimental 'postderef';
    print "aref-postderef: $_\n" for $aref->@*;
}
```

Here is an simple rule:

```
my @arr;               #array variable
my $arr_ref = \@arr;   #scalar - containing a reference to @arr

@{$arr_ref} is the same as @arr 
 ^^^^^^^^^^ - array reference in curly brackets
```

If you have an `$arrayref` - use the `@{$array_ref}` everywhere you want use the array.

```
my %hash;              #hash variable
my $hash_ref = \%hash; #scalar - containing a reference to %hash

%{$hash_ref} is the same as %hash
 ^^^^^^^^^^^ - hash reference in curly brackets
```

If you have an `$hash_ref` - use the `%{$hash_ref}` everywhere you want use the hash.

For the whole structure, the following

```
say $content->{items}->[0];
say $content->{items}[0];
say ${$content}{items}->[0];
say ${$content}{items}[0];
say ${$content->{items}}[0];
say ${${$content}{items}}[0];
```

prints the same value `1`.

Answer (score 7):

`$content` is a hash reference, so you always need to use an arrow to access its contents. `$content{items}` would refer to a `%content` hash, which you don't have. That's where you're getting that "use of uninitialized value" error from.

Comment: An alternative to using an invocation arrow when dereferencing is to use the notation `$$content{items}` as per [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References) docs.

Comment: TMTOWTDI strikes again!

Answer (score 2):

I actually asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037496/why-does-json-decode-return-a-scalar)

The answer:

> In Perl, a function can only really return a scalar or a list.
>
> Since hashes can be initialized or assigned from lists (e.g. %foo = (a => 1, b => 2)), I guess you're asking why json_decode returns something like { a => 1, b => 2 } (a reference to an anonymous hash) rather than (a => 1, b => 2) (a list that can be copied into a hash).
>
> I can think of a few good reasons for this:
>
> in Perl, an array or hash always contains scalars. So in something like { "a": { "b": 3 } }, the { "b": 3 } part has to be a scalar; and for consistency, it makes sense for the whole thing to be a scalar in the same way.
>
> if the hash is quite large (many keys at top-level), it's pointless and expensive to iterate over all the elements to convert it into a list, and then build a new hash from that list.
> in JSON, the top-level element can be either an object (= Perl hash) or an array (= Perl array). If json_decode returned a list in the former case, it's not clear what it would return in the latter case. After decoding the JSON string, how could you examine the result to know what to do with it? (And it wouldn't be safe to write %foo = json_decode(...) unless you already knew that you had a hash.) So json_decode's behavior works better for any general-purpose library code that has to use it without already knowing very much about the data it's working with.

I have to wonder exactly what you passed as an array to json_decode, because my results differ from yours.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use JSON qw (decode_json);
use Data::Dumper;
my $json = '["1", "2", "3", "4"]';

my $fromJSON = decode_json($json);

print Dumper($fromJSON);
```

The result is `$VAR1 = [ '1', '2', '3', '4' ];`

Which is an array ref, where your result is a hash ref

So did you pass in a hash with element items which was a reference to an array?

In my example you would get the array by doing

```
my @array = @{ $fromJSON };
```

In yours

```
my @array = @{ $content->{'items'} }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you dislike the arrow operator so much!

The `decode_json` function from the [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/module/JSON) module will *always* return a data reference.

Suppose you have a Perl program like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my $json_data = '{ "items": [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }';

my $content = decode_json($json_data);

use Data::Dump;
dd $content;
```

which outputs this text

```
{ items => [1 .. 4] }
```

showing that `$content` is a *hash reference*. Then you can access the array reference, as you found, with

```
dd $content->{items};
```

which shows

```
[1 .. 4]
```

and you can print the first element of the array by writing

```
print $content->{items}[0], "\n";
```

which, again as you have found, shows just

```
1
```

which is the first element of the array.

As `@cjm` mentions in a comment, it is *imperative* that you `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of *every* Perl program. If you had those in place in the program where you tried to access `$content{items}`, your program would have failed to compile, and you would have seen the message

```
Global symbol "%content" requires explicit package name
```

which is a (poorly-phrased) way of telling you that there is no `%content` so there can be no `items` element.

The *scalar* variable `$content` is *completely independent* from the *hash* variable `%content`, which you are trying to access when you write `$content{items}`. `%content` has never been mentioned before and it is empty, so there is no `items` element. If you had tried `@{$content->{items}}` then it would have worked, as would `@{${$content}{items}}`

If you *really* have a problem with the arrow operator, then you could write

```
print ${$content}{items}[0], "\n";
```

which produces the same output; but I don't understand what is wrong with the original version.